# How to construct an injection $A\to B$?

Tags: logic

We consider functions $A\to B$. Let $f$ be such a function $A\to B$. Furthermore, suppose that every function $A\to B$ is not surjective.

> How to construct an injection $A\to B$?

I have the following idea: We start with the function $f$, which has some "bugs" we want to fix to construct an injection $A\to B$ from that. This bugs are of the following form: There are several elements of $A$ which have the same function value. But since there is no surjection $A\to B$ it should not be a problem to fix this: There are enough other elements of $B$ (that are not hit by our function) to which we can send our elements of $A$. This is just my intuitive idea.

> How to formalize this idea?

Comment: Your idea is correct, if you have $\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\} \subset A$ with $f(a_i) = b$ for some fixed $b \in B$, you need to move the values of $f(a_2),f(a_3),\cdots, f(a_n)$. If $A$ is a finite set, things aren't so bad. But what if both $A$ and $B$ are infinite?

Comment: That case may be a bit harder. You'll likely need some form of choice depending on the cardinalities of the sets in question.

Comment: Which is why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I do not understand why people are disliking my question whithout explaining how I could improve my question...

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow, Why did you remove the set theory tag? Isn't that tag appropriate for this question? At least the answer uses set theoretic concepts.

Comment: @Rise At best, the `elementary-set-theory` tag would have been appropriate (definitely not the `set-theory` one though). You are free to add the latter though if you think it necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This answer does not use the function $f$. The existence of $f$ is replaced by the condition of $B$ being non-empty.

Consider the set $S$ of pairs $(U,g)$ with $U$ a subset of $A$ and $g\colon U\to B$ an injection. We define a partial order $\leq$ on $S$ by setting $(U,g) \leq (V,h)$ if $U\subset V$ and $h|_U = g$, that is, $h$ restricted to $U$ is $g$. The plan is as follows:

- We show using Zorn's lemma that there exists a maximal element $(U_0,g_0)$ of $S$.
- We show that $U_0 = A$.

For the first point, we have to show:

- $S$ is non-empty.
- Every ascending chain of elements of $S$ has an upper bound.

---

$S$ is non-empty. Indeed, the pair $(\emptyset, g_\emptyset)$, where $g_\emptyset \colon \emptyset \to B$ is the unique function from the empty set to $B$, lies in $S$.

Furthermore, let $(U_i,g_i)_{i\in I}$ be an ascending chain of elements of $S$. Define $U=\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ and define $g\colon U \to B$ as follows: let $x\in U$. Choose an $i\in I$ such that $x\in U_i$ and set $g(x)=g_i(x)$. This does not depend on the choice of $i$ since if say $i\leq j$ and $U_i \subset U_j$, then we have $g_i(x)=g_j(x)$. The function $g$ is injective since the $g_i$ are.

By Zorn's lemma there exists a maximal element $(U_0,g_0)$ of $S$. Now we show that $U_0 = A$.

Now assume there exists an element $x\in A\setminus U_0$. Choose an element $y\in B\setminus \mathrm{Im}(g_0)$. Here we use that $g_0$ is not surjective. Define $U_1 = U_0\cup \{x\}$ and $g_1\colon U_1 \to B$ by sending $x$ to $y$ and otherwise using $g_0$. Then $(U_1,f_1)$ is an element of $S$, in contradiction to the fact that $(U_0,f_0)$ was maximal.

Conclusion: if there exist no surjections $A\to B$ and if $B$ is not empty, then there exists an injection $A\to B$.

Comment: Is there an easier proof?

Comment: Maybe. However, I can't think of one that does not assume that A is at most countable. Do you have a specific question about the above proof?

Comment: One conceptually simpler proof is that if $|A|= \alpha$ and $|B|  = \beta$ then we must have $\alpha < \beta$, because otherwise there would be a surjection from $A$ to $B$. So we just take the canonical embedding of $\alpha$ into $\beta$ and this induces an injection of $A$ into $B$.